# A classe não é embutida no DOM(JQuery)

Tags: jquery, addclass

Seguinte código:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#inicio").hover(function() {
$("#inicio").addClass("fogo");
$("#inicio").removeClass("fogo");
});


});
</script>
```

E o HTML:

```
<li><a id="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
```

na classe*(.fogo)*, eu inseri estes códigos CSS, basicamente ele exibe um gif e o posiciona.

```
<style>
.fogo {
background-image: url("http://www.bestgraph.com/gifs/paysages/flammes/flammes-10.gif");
background-position: 0px center;
}
</style>
```

Esqueçam estilização, eu retirei os css para ficar mais fácil de visualizar o código.
Eu testei aqui, e ao passar o mouse em cima de "a", ele recebe uma classe, vazia, ficando algo como:

```
<li><a id="inicio" class="">Inicio</a></li>
```

O que faço para simplesmente colocar a classe .fogo no elemento, e ao sair o mouse retira-la? Para mim basicamente usando hover, e duas funções, a primeira para entrada do mouse sobre o elemento, e outra trabalhando na saída..
Grato!

Comment: Olá, eu consegui corrigir o problema, na verdade era apenas o mal uso do hover. Com o evento hover eu faço a mesma coisa que os amigos ali sugestionaram, só que com menos código! 
Ele pede duas funções, a primeira para quando o mouse estar em cima do elemento(mouseenter) e a segunda função é para quando o mouse sair do elemento(mouseleave).
Basicamente ficou assim:

$("#inicio").hover(function() {
$("#inicio").addClass("fogo");},
function() {
$("#inicio").removeClass("fogo");}
);
Até mais, agradeço a todos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu estás a adicionar a classe e logo depois a remover a mesma.

No DOM notas que o atributo `class` é adicionado mas vazio porque o jQuery adiciona a classe ao elemento onde para o efeito aplica o atributo `class` mas logo depois como estás a remover a classe do elemento, o jQuery retira a classe mas deixa o atributo `class` vazio.

O teu HTML inicial:

```
<li><a id="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
```

Após usares o método [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/):

```
<li><a id="inicio" class="fogo">Inicio</a></li>
```

Após usares o método [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/):

```
<li><a id="inicio" class="">Inicio</a></li>
```

## Solução

Parece-me que pretendes adicionar a classe quando o rato está por cima do elemento e remover quando o rato deixa de estar sobre o elemento, então podes alterar o teu código para o seguinte:

```
$( "#inicio" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $("#inicio").addClass("fogo");    
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $("#inicio").removeClass("fogo");    
  });
```

Assim delegamos dois eventos no elemento alvo, o [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) para despoletar uma ação quando o rato vai para cima do elemento, e o [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) para quando o rato deixa de estar em cima do elemento.

Answer (score 4):

Vivas!
O teu problema está no uso dos eventos errados.
Devias usar o mouseover e o mouseout

olha um exemplo a funcionar:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //evento quando o rato fica sob o elemento #inicio
    $("#inicio").mouseover(
      function(){
       $("#inicio").addClass("fogo");
      });
    //evento quando o rato sai sobre o elemento #inicio
    $("#inicio").mouseout(
        function(){
            $("#inicio").removeClass("fogo");
        });
});
```

Link do meu teste no jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zgkcnLpd/
Espero que ajude.